# VBA function cannot return value to main sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem:

Now I got a date range for a main sub (20160706-20160805) and I have to separate the value and put it as a date. What I do is:

```
Main sub date () 

Dim strDaterage as string 

Dim startdate as date 

'For the sake of simplicity, just use the hard code for the date 

strDaterange = "20160706-20160805"

startdate = findstartdate()

msgbox (startdate)

End sub
```

And for the function to separate the date an extract the value:

```
Function findstartdate()

    daterange = "20160706-20160805"
    startDateange = Left(daterange, 8)
    startYear = Left(startDateange, 4)
    startMonth = Mid(startDateange, 5, 2)
    startDay = Right(startDateange, 2)
    startdate = DateSerial(startYear, startMonth, startDay)

End Function
```

I try using the byval and byfer but it still does not work. How can I return the date value back into the main sub?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't return anything from your function. You are missing the line: `findstartdate = startdate`

Comment: This also works, many thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are using a `String` as an input, but if you want you can use the code below (there are more efficient ways to do it).

Your Sub :

```
Sub SubDate()

Dim strDaterage     As String
Dim startdate       As Date

strDaterage = "20160706-20160805"
startdate = findstartdate(strDaterage)

MsgBox (startdate)

End Sub
```

Your function:

```
' need to add a String variable as an input, and return tha value as a Date
Function findstartdate(DateRange As String) As Date

startDateange = Left(DateRange, 8)
startYear = Left(startDateange, 4)
startMonth = Mid(startDateange, 5, 2)
startDay = Right(startDateange, 2)

startdate = DateSerial(startYear, startMonth, startDay)

' convert the string result to a Date
findstartdate = CDate(startdate)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Actually my task is to extract the entry from the csv files from google analytics, therefore the input is the string.